# Generating a list containing range of numbers from min and max values

Tags: c#, range

I'm trying to generate a list containing range of numbers from a given min and max values.

If my min value is 14500 and max value is 58000 then I need the method to return;

Less than Rs. 20000
Rs. 20,001 - Rs. 30,000
Rs. 30,001 - Rs. 40,000
Rs. 40,001 - Rs. 50,001
Rs. 50,001 and above

- There should be only 6 or less range items in the result.
- The end value should be rounded to the next 10th, 100th or 1000th etc...
  depending on the value.

My question is similar to this [php question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012329/how-to-create-price-range-dynamically-with-php), but I'd like to make use of `LINQ` if possible.

I've tried `Enumerable.Range` and some code using a lot of `for` and `while`.
What is the best ways to do this?

Comment: What if you have `min=10000` and `max = 90000` there is more than 6 possible elements based on your rules. Which ones should be taken to comply with rule `There should be only 6 or less range items in the result` ?

Comment: @Michael in that case, results like `<=20000, 20001-40000, 40001-60000, 60001-80000, >=80000` or 
`<=15000, 15001-30000, 30001-45000, 45001-60000, 60001-75000, 75001-90000` or
`<=15000, 15001-30000, 30001-45000, 45001-60000, 60001-75000, >=75001` are acceptable.

Comment: If this is for an ecommerce website, I think you're better of defining strategic price ranges for each category. 

For example, check this http://www.flipkart.com/home-entertainment/televisions/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=ckf%2Cczl&filterNone=true

They have products from 8,000 to all the way upto 2,80,000. I think there approach is good with the final filter item being "60,000 and above" as there are relatively fewer products in that range and it includes a specific segment of high paying customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program will take into account only the max value, because you are saying that you can accept below 6 price ranges.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int maxItems = 6;
        int minItems = 3;
        int maxValue = 99232;
        int minValue = 99000;

        //the list to store string formmated items
        List<string> finalList = new List<string>();

        int divider = (GetBestValue(maxValue, minValue, maxItems, minItems));

        int startingPoint = ((minValue / divider) + 1) * divider;

        finalList.Add(string.Format("less then {0}", startingPoint));

        int currentAmmount = startingPoint;

        while (currentAmmount < maxValue)
        {
            if (currentAmmount + divider > maxValue)
                finalList.Add(string.Format("{0} and above", currentAmmount + 1));
            else
                finalList.Add(string.Format("rs. {0} - rs. {1}", currentAmmount + 1, currentAmmount + divider));

            currentAmmount += divider;
        }

        foreach (var item in finalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method will seek the best divider to take 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="max">Max value to use</param>
    /// <param name="maxItems"></param>
    /// <param name="minValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static int GetBestValue(int max, int min, int maxItems, int minItems) 
    {

        int currentDivider = 1;
        int currentItems;
        int startingMaxValue = max;
        int range = (max - min);

        while (startingMaxValue/10 > 0)
        {
            currentDivider *= 10;
            startingMaxValue /= 10;
        }

        //check aginst max value
        while (max / currentDivider > maxItems) 
        {
            currentDivider *= 2;
        }

        //check aginst min items

        currentItems =range / currentDivider;

        while (currentItems < minItems) 
        {
            currentDivider /= 2;
            currentItems = range / currentDivider;

        }

        return currentDivider;
    }
}
```

If you want to take into account the min value, you must provide with some logic of how it will divide the range

Comment: Can you help me get started to integrate the `min value` also in the calculation of `divider`? `min value` will be less than `100000`.

Comment: The first question should be- how many minimum items do you want? (i.e 6 is the maximum, what is the minimum?)

Comment: I want minimum 3 items. If `min=89` and `max=275` then I want the method to return `less than 100, 101-200 and 201 & above`

Comment: I've added min value support, it might needs a bit twiking but seems to be working well.

Answer (score 1):

Here could be mistakes because I am writing this in notepad but you will get the idea:

```
var start = min - min % 10000 + 10000;

list.Add(string.Format("less then {0}", start));

while(start < max)
{
    if(start + 10000 > max)
       list.Add(string.Format("{0} and above", start + 1)); 
    else   
       list.Add(string.Format("rs. {0} - rs. {1}", start + 1, start + 10000));

    start += 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Note that this answer returns all the numbers in the ranges. Which might not be needed. I'll leave this answer in here for those searching for a different answer.

I'm not using LINQ. But this method allows you to partition the numbers. It goes from min to first partition as in: min = 1563, partition = 100 then first list is 1563 to 1600. Next one is 1601 to 1700.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var numberRange in NumberRanges(14500, 58000, 10000))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(": {0}, {1}", numberRange.Min(), numberRange.Max());
    }
}

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> NumberRanges(int min, int max, int partitionSize)
{
    int num = min;

    List<int> numPart = new List<int>(partitionSize);
    while (num <= max)
    {
        numPart.Add(num++);
        if (num % partitionSize == 0)
        {
            numPart.Add(num++);
            yield return numPart;
            numPart.Clear();
        }
    }
    if (numPart.Any())
        yield return numPart;
}
```

You can force only 6 lists maximum by doing:

```
NumberRanges(14500, 100000, 10000).Take(6);
```

Giving:

[image: Output]