# How to create a Price Range dynamically with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, e-commerce

I've already seen another question related, but is not what I want. Reference -> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012329/how-to-create-price-range-dynamically-with-php)

I would like to create a price range filter for an e-commerce site. A lot of sites, have dynamic price range filter.

```
<label>Less than $500 (800) <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1"/></label>
<label>$500 - $1.000 (921) <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="2"/></label>
<label>More than $1.000 (1021) <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="3"/></label>
```

For i.e. Accesories for less than $500 and shoes for more than $1.000 (if the user enter in the catalog) If user enter to a category, this must change to something like this

```
<label>Less than $1.500 (40) <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="1"/></label>
<label>$1500 - $2.000 (43) <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="2"/></label>
<label>More than $2.000 (50) <input type="checkbox" name="price[]" value="3"/></label>
```

I use PHP, Jquery & MySQL.

Don't worry about querying after because I will use an already method that works for range. The issue here is how to generate dynamically groups.

Thank you so much in advance. This is my very first post here. I think I made this understandable. Hope you can help me!

**EDIT:**

The idea is the filter show something like this:

- First 30% of products in 1st price range
- Subsequent 33% in 2nd price range
- Last 37% in 3th price range

The percentage are not important but has to be balance.

I'll add some images for references

**Amazon Price Filter for PCs**

[Picture of Amazon Price Filter for PCs](https://i.ibb.co/8696rZG/Captura-de-Pantalla-2020-07-10-a-la-s-13-33-11.png)

**Amazon Price Filter for Macbooks**

[Amazon Price Filter for Macbooks](https://i.ibb.co/0KkQy3X/Captura-de-Pantalla-2020-07-10-a-la-s-13-36-10.png)

I need to know HOW TO GENERATE the ranges. The ranges MUST BE dynamic according to the proportion of quantity.

**ANSWER:**

Thanks for the answer to @markus-ao

here is my solution for this problem:

First, count the table's total rows.

i.e. 1000 rows, divided by 3 --> 333

Use LIMIT to get the range of the middle between 33% and 66% of the total.

```
SELECT min(price) mini, max(price) maxi
from (SELECT price FROM products order by price ASC limit 333, 333) x
```

And you can use it as this

```
$lessthan = $results['mini'];
$morethan = $results['maxi'];

echo '<button>Less than $lessthan</button>
<button>$lessthan - $morethan</button>
<button>More than $morethan</button>';
```

I though it will be more complicated but @markus-ao explained very well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You did not provide an example of a 'dynamic group'. Your question is very unclear as it's not clear if you need a HTML, PHP, or JavaScript solution. It's also not clear what is not working. Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and then provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to dynamically create groups of price ranges based on the category selected?

Comment: Hey Twisty. Thanks for the answer. I will edit it. Thanks

Comment: @MarkusAO Yes, kindda. I added more info about it. And use an example of Amazon. Price range in base of the products showed, and balance with quantity. There is no sense if I have 95% of the products in one price range

Comment: @NicolásFehn this is done in your PHP. You want to examine the SQL Results and then perform a Count of the items that match certain criteria. Your example will need to show us some amount of example data that might be generated by your SQL Lookup. Alternately, you can perform small queries that then give you the number of items in a specific price range for a specific category.

Comment: Okay, clear enough what you're looking for. I jotted down a walk-through with code samples you can start customizing to fit your use-case.

Comment: Thanks for updating the post with your implementation. Right, if you only need to show the mid-range and options for "less than" and "more than", rather than specify the lowest/highest cutoff for the flanking ranges, then all you need to do is query the ordered chunk in the middle. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a plug-and-play answer. The following will give you the necessary leads for sorting this out. I trust you can compose the necessary PHP SQL boilerplate yourself to fill in the gaps, and turn this into a functioning implementation. (If not, hire me and my lolcats. =^o^=)

First of all, you'll want to find out the general lay of the land in your category's products. The example assumes a `products` table with columns called `price` and `category`.

```
SELECT
    MIN(price) AS min_price, 
    MAX(price) AS max_price, 
    AVG(price) AS avg_price,
    COUNT(*) AS total_items 
FROM products
WHERE category = 3
```

This query will give you the minimum, average, and maximum prices in a given category, along with a total count of items. (We only really need the total count here, feel free to remove the min/max/avg if not useful.) Let's fetch that with PHP into a variable `$cat` (or `$meow`). Then, now that we know the total amount of products, we can look up the MAX of the first 33%, and the MIN of the last 33% of the cat's products to get our balanced price ranges' break-points.

```
// Assuming 1000 items, one third floored is 333.

$rangesize = floor($cat['total_items'] / 3);

// Get the min/max/total of the bottom 1/3, let's imagine we fetch it into $low:

SELECT 
    MIN(price) as low_min,
    MAX(price) as low_max,
    COUNT(*) AS low_total 
FROM (SELECT price FROM products 
WHERE category = 3
ORDER BY price ASC
LIMIT 0, $rangesize) low_prices // lowest price first, first 1/3 of records
```

Here the ORDER and LIMIT clauses narrow us to the 0-333 cheapest items. The `COUNT(*)` really is a bit redundant here, since we already know the number of items we've limited the query to. Anyway, there it is. Feel free to remove it and just use `$rangesize` later for totals.

```
// Get the min/max/total of the top 1/3, let's imagine we fetch it into $high:

SELECT 
    MIN(price) as high_min,
    MAX(price) as high_max,
    COUNT(*) AS high_total
FROM (SELECT price FROM products 
WHERE category = 3
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 0, $rangesize) high_prices // highest price first, first 1/3 of records
```

Here the ORDER and LIMIT clauses narrow us to the 0-333 priciest items. **Edit:** We're using a subquery to get the result set with the X lowest prices. This is because `MIN/MAX/AVG` aggregates are processed *before* the `ORDER/LIMIT` clauses. (`COUNT` however reflects the final result set.)

Then, we have all the necessary data. Now let's put it all together. *DynGroup::CompilesThou(!)*

```
$group = [
    'low' => [ 
        'start' => $low['low_min'],
        'end' => $low['low_max'],
        'total' => $low['low_total']
    ],
    'mid' => [
        'start' => $low['low_max'],
        'end' => $high['high_min'],
        'total' => ($cat['total_items'] - $low['low_total'] - $high['high_total']) 
    ],
    'high' => [ 
        'start' => $high['high_min'],
        'end' => $high['high_max'],
        'total' => $high['high_total']
    ]
];
```

And there you have your sample dynamic price range group ready for action. You'll notice we derived the mid-range values from the low and high values, rather than running yet another query for it. I trust you know how to turn the array into HTML labels and checkboxes.

If you want to generate more options, simply modify the divisor for the total products (in our `$rangesize =` line earlier), and add the necessary queries to get the data you want. For five options, divide by 5 and add queries for lowMid and midHigh ranges, each 20% of the total. If you want to have 30/40/30 or whatever spreads, just do the necessary math etc.

You will probably want to cache your calculations, and refresh them periodically. (I'd just have a single maintenance script that iterates all categories and saves them for front-end use.)

To ensure you don't have products below the query cut-line, you'll want your *low-end* query to *actually* look for prices between 0-`low_max` (instead of the stated range), in case you add a product cheaper than the minimum on record in between cache refreshes. So too for the *high-end* query, rather look for `high_min`-9999999 or whatever is well over the top. Simply `WHERE price > $high_min` and `price < $low_max AND category = 3` would do the job.

With enough time, enthusiasm and dexterity, a clever SQL craftsman could probably put all of the above into a single, dense query with subqueries and stuff. I felt this was a more educational path for an answer. Hope it helps. Happy crafting; let me know if anything's unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your faster and educational answer. But there is a problem, I think... When you have a LIMIT, it limits just the rows that fetch, no the information on the select. Is this correct? Anyway, you open my mind for the answer, but now I need to get the max value of that 3 segments. I'm using MYSQL

Comment: Could be through two queries, or subselects. St like "SELECT max(price) FROM (select price from products limit 0, $rangesize) t"

Comment: When we use `ORDER by price ASC` and `LIMIT 0, 333`, MySQL takes the 333 cheapest products, and your `MIN` and `MAX` will match that range. `LIMIT` is applied *after* `ORDER` yousee. The queries in my answer should already accomplish what you're looking for. That said, feel free to craft this into subqueries if you wish. I try to avoid them in dev phase unless there's an argument to be made on how subqueries make it more readable and easier to debug...

Comment: Apologies: On a quick test-drive, it seems that aggregate functions like MIN, MAX, AVG indeed get applied *before* `ORDER/LIMIT` (but after `WHERE`), rather than on the final result set. (Which would give you the min/max of the entire set.) Will review possibilities and revise the answer, but it does look like subqueries must happen!

Comment: Thanks! Hahaha I though my MySQL was crazy. Everything looks awesome, just one correction for future people looking this, LIMIT must be $beginning, $qtofrows // 0, 333 for low // 333, 333 for middle // 666, 333 for the rest. Thank you so much for your time. I'll make some testing and mark your answer as the answer!

Comment: Excellent. I've just corrected the answer with appropriate subqueries and actually tested them, and things seem to work as expected. :) Also I've reversed the high-end (sub)query to `price DESC`, which lets our LIMIT/OFFSET clause be identical with the low-end query, to keep things simple. (N.B. MySQL doesn't allow OFFSET with unlimited post-offset results, duh.)